# Can't add rightBarButton to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've subclassed `UINavigationController` to my pop & push needs and now I want to add a custom background image and some custom buttons to the `UINavigationBar`. 
I've read that I can do it (since iOS 5) inside the appdelegate but I'd like to keep it inside the `UINavigationController` subclass for future use.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *rightbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [rightbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 0, 56, 39)];
    [rightbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(popMePlease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightbutton];
    [[self  navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButton];
}
```

But I can't see the rightBarButton. I don't know if `viewDidLoad` is the place to put it in.

Comment: your code working fine once check image name?

Comment: The image isn't the problem because if i'll add this line of code I will see the button on the view:                            `[self.view addSubview:rightbutton];`

Comment: Why have you written `[self  navigationItem]...` in the code? Shouldn't it be `[self.navigationItem]...`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code button x position starts from 280 . It shoud be near to 0.

Replace following line

```
[rightbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 0, 56, 39)];
```

with

```
[rightbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 56, 39)];
```

Comment: Nop, location isn't the problem.

Comment: except location I don't find any issue in your code. it should work. may be currunt view controller in not in navigation stack. you can check by UINavigationController's viewControllers property.

Comment: Yes, x value for the UIButton when you are setting it as UIBarButtonItem's custom view does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working fine.

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imTitleBG.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
 UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithCustomView:myButton];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=btn;

-(void)Action
{

// Do what you want here 

}
```

try this code might be helpful to you...